# Extracting metadata from data

Tags: c#, metadata, extract

I have data in c# as below,

```
 public class TabularData<TRow, TCol>
{
    public TabularData()
    {
        Data = new Dictionary<ComplexPropertyName, Object>();
    }

    public TableHeader<TRow>[] RowHeader { get; set; }
    public TableHeader<TCol>[] ColumnHeader { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<ComplexPropertyName, Object> Data { get; set; }
}

public class TableHeader<TId>
{
    public TId Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; internal set; }
    public bool HasChildren { get; set; }
    public LevelValue LevelValue { get; set; }
    public Object Total { get; set; }
    public Tuple<object, object> SummaryTracker { get; set; }
}
```

And accessing data as below,

```
private void ProcessDataNew(TabularData<long, long> data, string[] rowHdrTitles)
{
    // Process data here...
}
```

I want to separate metedata  from the data to process it.

Ex: At client side we have separated metedata as below using serializers,
[image]

How can we do it using plain c#?

Comment: What do you mean by metadata?

Comment: Agree with @LeiNaD_87: what do you mean with metadata? In your TabularData class you can TRow.GetType() to get the .NET type, for example. Or maybe you can apply some constraint to the generic type TRow and TCol with the keyword "where".

Comment: i have added the image .